# Java shutdown function on jar unloading

Tags: java

Is there a mechanism in Java that would allow me to imbue a function or runnable into something-or-other that will be called if the jar *is about to get unloaded*?

Note that the JVM will, in general, stay up. That rules out `Runtime.addShutdownHook`.

(It's required to facilitate hot redeployment to a web server).

Comment: Define 'jar unloaded'. It's meaningless to me. Do you mean '*WAR* unloaded'?

Comment: *WAR unloaded* sounds like some tent-pole sequel to the matrix trilogy. What I mean is that we can push a replacement jar into a jvm which, of course, cannot happen until the original jar is detached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing in Java SE, as far as I'm aware.

But since you mention "web server", you might be looking at a Java EE solution. And then there's [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Just implement that interface and configure the implementing class in your `web.xml`.

For a pure Java SE solution, I would not bind the library-loading to a class, but to an instance instead. This way you can have tighter control over when it is loaded and unloaded.

You could even use `finalize` here, as that's one of the few cases where it would be appropriate. This would have the drawback of being non-deterministic (i.e. you can't depend on the object being finalized when the new version is being loaded).

Comment: Perfect. Better still is that my colleague will have to do the implementation.